# Custom Renderer for ContentView (iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, background, xamarin.forms

I have a delared the following

```
public class ViewBase : ContentView
{
    //...
}
```

When I use that in XAML

```
<local:ViewBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyForms;"
    x:Class="MyForms.Finder" 
    BackgroundColor="Color.Yellow">

    <!-- ... -->

</local:ViewBase>
```

When I use a CustomRenderer for that and even (as below) do nothing in it, the BackgroundColor from above is not set. When I don't define the following lines the background is yellow as expected.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewBase), typeof(ViewRendererBase))]
namespace MyiOS
{    
    public class ViewRendererBase : ViewRenderer
    {
    }
}
```

BackgroundColor is a Property of ViewRenderer. I had a look into the code, it seems as Control is no set (I don't call SetNativeControl) it can't set Control.BackgroundColor to a value. But why does this happen? My guess is that something is wrong with the inheritance of ViewRenderer, as the default behaviour uses something different on ContentView!?

Comment: Did you try giving it a width and a height? They are probably 0.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the View itself, size and layout are correct. But the BackgroundColor-Property is not working when I define my own (empty) CustomRenderer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure whether this is a bug in our docs [1] or a bug in the iOS `ViewRenderer` code [2] for the `SetBackgroundColor` method. So there are a couple of ways to workaround this. One is to have your custom renderer inherit from `VisualElementRenderer<T>` instead, e.g.:

```
public class ViewBaseRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<ContentView>
{
    //...
}
```

When checking on the default renderer type in iOS code with:

```
var contentRenderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(new ContentView())
var rendererType = contentRenderer.GetType();
```

`rendererType` is a `VisualElementRenderer<T>`, so this would seem to be the default renderer that is used by Forms, so it would seem to be a bug in the docs.

Another "workaround" would be to use the `ViewRenderer` but override the `SetBackgroundColor` method:

```
public class ViewBaseRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
    protected override void SetBackgroundColor(Color color)
    {
        base.SetBackgroundColor(color);

        if (NativeView == null)
            return;

        if (color != Color.Default)
            NativeView.BackgroundColor = color.ToUIColor();
    }
```

I have brought this up with the Xamarin Forms team to determine whether it is a bug in the docs or a bug in the Forms iOS Platform code for the `ViewRenderer`. If you look at the forms source code I linked [2] you will see that if `Control` is null, which it is in this case, the background color is never set. By overriding and adding the code to set the background color for `NativeView` then you can workaround this possible bug.

So apparently it seems the docs are in error. If you use `ViewRenderer` you have to set the `Control` yourself. Other renderers that inherit from `ViewRenderer`, like `LabelRender`, set the `Control` already, but `ViewRenderer` does not, so you would have to call `SetNativeControl()` in the `OnElementChanged` override to create and set a native control. See this forum post [3]. Personally, I think that one should inherit from the renderer that is used by default, which in this case is a `VisualElementRenderer<T>`

[1] https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/renderers/#Layouts

[2] https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/ViewRenderer.cs#L99

[3] https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/180839#Comment_180839

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. VisualElementRenderer<ContentView> was exactly what I was looking for and didn't find. As for the other approach, SetNativeControl(NativeView) apparently doesn't work, there is an error: can't add view to itself (or something like that).